# Image and text editor like PicSay android app

Tags: android, photo, resize-image, text-editor

I am developing an image editing app like [PicSay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shinycore.picsayfree&hl=en) android app, in which I have to put text on image with custom background and also user can resize text by touch/controller on screen. I try lots of things but I can’t do that, please help me for that and is there any API available in the android for image editor?

Thnaks,
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Aviary SDK](http://www.aviary.com/android) for developing Photo Editing Project.

*or*

You can use [OPENCV for image processing](http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/).

I hope this might help you.

Answer (score -1):

I think use this demo code may be help full to you.

Java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        /*Put you code */
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return false;
    }

}
```

xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/test"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
    </EditText>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: thnx for reply, but i want to change EditText width and height by touch or controller on screen like PicSay Android app.